# What determines the phase difference between two voltages at an AC bus?

Tags: power, power-engineering, power-grid

At an AC bus, the power flow is given by the following equation :

[image]

In normal operation, the voltages (V1, V2), as well as the inductive resistance (x), are constants. So the parameter δ defines the power flow.

I would like to ask if the value of δ is constant. If not, what are the parameters that determine its value?

Comment: I think you should be a bit more precise and descriptive in your question. I believe you are asking for power flowing at some other element (probably a transmission line?), as you have two different voltages (so two different buses? do you know what a bus is?). X is denoted as reactance, not inductive resistance. The formula you gave only holds if the line has no resistance, it's an approximation. Also, delta is not a parameter, but a state of your system, just like V1 and V2. Even though you can assume V1 and V2 to be constants, this may not hold in "_normal operation_"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\$\delta\$ is called the power angle. It is the difference in phases between \$ V_1 \$ and \$ V_2 \$. You are correct that depending on its value, positive or negative, it determines the direction of power flow.

$$\delta = \phi_2 - \phi_1$$

Since \$ \phi_2 \$ and \$ \phi_1 \$ can vary, \$ \delta \$ is therefore variable.